# GPS or Printable map?

Tags: geospatial, city, global, travel

Question for you guys, especially travelers like me do you prefer GPS or printable maps? I don't know but from my latest trip, GPS wasn't much of help. I had to resort to pdf maps from this site http://vectormap.info/ which have been very useful.

Comment: Do you have your own smartphone like IPhone ? that should help you but I know in some areas they won't show up due to lack of coverage. How do you use this PDF ? What is the purpose for using your GPS ? What kind of GPS do you have ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because spam o rama

Comment: I only use GPS on smartphone, Samsung not iPhone :(

Comment: Ok, It seems like the GPS on smartphone are not always correct. Sometimes it takes a while for it calibrate itself. Have you looked up GPS apps on your Samsung ?

Comment: If [you](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213275/115) or [Lalu](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/83891/lalu) have any connection to the maps that you are promoting here then I think you should disclose that before posing a question to which you want to propose them as a solution..

Answer (score 2):

I always bring a GPS and *two* paper maps: one in my mapcase around my neck, and a backup map in my rucksack, in case I lose my mapcase including map.  The screen on a GPS receiver is far too small for wilderness navigation, it relies on batteries and on coverage (can be problematic in narrow canyons).  If I had to choose one I would certainly take only the paper map.  A paper map always works.

Of course, the importance of either depends on where you are hiking.  I usually hike off-trail and navigate based on streams, lakes, and mountains.  The GPS is mostly a toy, but can save a lot of time in dense fog.  When you're hiking on well-signposted trails in an American state park or in the vicinity of Swiss towns such as Zermatt and Grindelwald, you don't really *need* either a GPS or a map.  I still take both (although in this case just one copy of the map), but I'm a topographic map nerd who takes one even when it's essentially useless.

Comment: Exactly, screen too small haha but thanks for your answer I'm learning a lot here :)